# Issues with tracing bitmaps and vectors (AS3)

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, adobe

I am having strange issues with tracing bitmaps that have been imported into flash pro CS6

I import large HD bitmaps into flash and then trace them to vector and then shrink the vector down about 1/15th the size of the original. This allow me to used bitmap images without the grainy pixelization look.

I have done this for quite some time but on my current project the traced vectors are causing the flash program to lag really bad and the published ios version is lagging horribly as well

Not sure if Im missing some thing, please help

Comment: This is pretty much the worst option for the performance. It generates tons of vectors that take a lot of renering. Why don't you just scale down the bitmap image to the correct size with anti-aliasing? Bitmaps are usually the way to go on mobiles

Comment: How can a "downsized" HD image become pixelated? Where you scaling down via code? Did you try the `smoothing = true;` option for the container (Sprite or MC) of the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely because your vectors contain too many points.

You can use the [smooth tool](https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/using/reshape-lines-shapes.html#straightenandsmoothlines) to go from this<sup>c</sup>:

[image: many points]

to that<sup>c</sup>:

[image: few points]

Or [optimize curves](https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/using/reshape-lines-shapes.html#optimizecurves) to get a similar effect like so<sup>c</sup>:

[image: optimize curves]

---

<sup>c</sup> images under [CC BY-NC-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/), click them for source